# No route to host - Proxy issue

Tags: networking, proxy, browser

In my office,proxy is enabled in my system .When i use wget for downloading,The terminal giving "No route to host" issue.But when i connect to the same site using browser,It is connecting.I've configured the proxy settings in my browser.Seems like I have to do some setting in my system.
 Pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For wget to work, you need to set http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables. E.g.:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxyhost:8080/"
export https_proxy="http://proxyhost:8080/"
```

You can check what values are set by executing:

```
echo $http_proxy
```

Generally, it is better to set your browser to "Use system proxy settings" and then configure proxy under "System -> Preferences -> Network Proxy" (and apply system-wide). This sets proxy settings in various places. However, I'm not sure if this configures above mentioned environment variables as well.

Comment: K thats worked..